# Extracting GPS Metadata from Samsung Note 8 Android Video

Tags: android, video, gps, location, metadata

I am looking to see if anyone knows how to extract metadata from Android video files to pinpoint GPS coordinates at different points throughout the video. I see sites that do it for photos, but not for video files. My GPS location was running the entire time the video was shot. I am looking to track the route I traveled as the video was going for a good 15-20 minutes. Thanks!!

- Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with the desktop command line, [exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool) MAY be able to help.  The problem lies in the fact that there is no set standard for GPS data in a video.

If you run the command
`exiftool -gps* -ee FILE`
(replace FILE with the name of the file you wish to process) and you get an extended output, a stream of gps locations, then you'll be able to convert the data into a geo track.

Grab the [gpx format file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/exiftool/exiftool/master/fmt_files/gpx.fmt), place it in the current directory, and then run the command
`exiftool -p gpx.fmt FILE >out.gpx`
and you should have a gpx track to work with.

If exiftool isn't able to read gps data from the video, try asking for help on the [exiftool forums](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php).  Phil (the author) has been very good in adding support for gps data in videos lately.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this, however my cmd knowledge is not very strong. How do i get the gpx format file? Is there any easier option to do this?

Comment: To get the GPX format file, follow the link above and save it.  I don't know of another way, but I haven't looked.  It's entirely possible that exiftool won't be able to extract the gps data, but if it doesn't, the author of exiftool might be able to add it if you can provide a sample and post it over at the exiftool forums.